# What is the "first language"?

Tags: historical-linguistics, evolutionary-linguistics

I vaguely remember reading an article about a book that talked about what the "first language" would have consisted of, but I can't seem to recall what the book was or what the language was called. What is the first language or the origin of language called? The Proto-Proto-Proto-language?

Comment: If you are open to the idea (and not everyone is), you will want to read about the possible consequences of a population bottle neck in the history of humans, where there were only a few thousand humans. The probably at most spoke 1 to a few languages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The name you're looking for is [Proto-World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Human_language). However, we have no way of knowing whether there actually ever was only a single proto-language ([monogenesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenesis_%28linguistics%29)) or whether language developed independently multiple times ([polygenesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygenesis_%28linguistics%29)). Some arguments may be more plausible in this regard than others, but it remains speculation. You can find more about this debate in [Monogenesis vs. Polygenesis](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/682/444) and [Do the Khoisan languages resemble the world's first language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/663/444)

Even if we could assume there was one proto-language to all the world's languages, the comparative method - the only proven methodology in historical linguistics - would not be able to tell us what that language looked like, since it has a limit of some six to ten thousand years time depth. Proto-World would have to have existed at least fifty thousand years ago.

Comment: Ah, this is great. I think the book I'm thinking of named the language something else, but that may have just been for the purpose of giving it a simpler name. Ill have to check these resources out!

Comment: Proto-Sapiens perhaps? If there are other names out there I'm curious about those...

Comment: It was something that began with an "A." I think Ant- or an- or al- or something. It was something I saw in passing and I forgot to bookmark to look at later, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for "Adamic?"

It is thought by some of the Jewish, Christian, and Islamic faiths that the "Divine Language" handed down by God would be the [Adamic Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamic_language). So, it is possible the line you came across was using "Adamic" for Proto-World or the like.

Comment: Bingo! That's the word! I knew it was something with an A that referred to Proro-World!

Comment: Good. Just make a note that "Adamic Language" and "Proto-World" _do not_ describe the same thing.